# how fix when i click on the twelve item from gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i have a problem, all items before the number twelve is ok, but starting on twelve when i click on that item and the next items return open the new activity but with other position , i mean when i click on the item number twelve , return me the value number three.

this is my code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                objAllBean=arrayOfLatestVideo.get(position);
                int pos=objAllBean.getId();

                Intent intplay=new Intent(getActivity(),VideoPlay.class);
                intplay.putExtra("POSITION", pos);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", allArrayVideo);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_CATNAME", allArrayVideoCatName);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_CATID", allArrayVideoCatId);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", allArrayVideourl);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_NAME", allArrayVideoName);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_CID", allArrayVideoId);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_DURATION", allArrayVideoDuration);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_DISCRIPTION", allArrayVideoDesc);
                intplay.putExtra("VIDEO_IMAGE_URL",allArrayImageUrl);

                startActivity(intplay);    
            }
```

Layout Grid

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/lsv_latest"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:numColumns="@integer/columns" <-- 3
       android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth">    
   </GridView>    
</FrameLayout>
```

item gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp">    

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#009ACC"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="1dp"
          />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="HD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:background="#9a000000"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />    
    </LinearLayout>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try to `debug` and catch the mistake..

Comment: on debug mode looks ok, but continue having that problem, :(